# java lambda:How to count total items in a list?

Tags: java, lambda

How can I return the following result by lambda?

```
int total = 0;
for (User user : userList) {
    total += user.getAge();
}
```

I know reduce's use.`new LinkedList<Integer>().stream().reduce(0, (acc, x) -> acc + x)`
I want to try(but failed). `userList.stream().reduce(0, (acc, x) -> acc.getAge() + x.getAge());`

Comment: Your title is unclear. You want to find `total` - so why have you mentioned as `List<Object>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `mapToInt`

```
useList
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(User::getAge)
    .sum();
```

If you really wanted to use `reduce`, here it is (but I don't see a point in using it as the above is more readable)

```
useList.stream()
        .mapToInt(User::getAge)
        .reduce(0, (acc, current) -> acc + current);
```

Or as suggested by Holger@

```
user.stream()
    .reduce(0, (c, user) -> c + user.getAge(), (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Comment: Or `user .stream() .reduce(0, (c, u) -> c + u.getAge(), (a, b) -> a + b);`. By the way, the OP already added the missing `r`s in `User` and `user`…

Comment: @Holger The version of `reduce` that takes 3 params did not come to my mind when I wrote the answer. Thanks :)